# Using constraints in Rails to change the default root_path for some users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I was looking for a way to change the default routing (root_path specifically) of my app using something other than a simple if/then check for different types of users. I found [this](http://minhajuddin.com/2011/10/24/how-to-change-the-rails-root-url-based-on-the-user-or-role) code example online, however I can't make it work with my app and the main problem is that I simply don't  understand what the underlying code does, therefore I cannot adapt the code to my app.

First I create this rule in my router:

```
root 'admin#index', constraints: RoleConstraint.new(:admin)
```

Then I create a new file called role_constrait.rb in my lib directory and user this code:

```
class RoleConstraint
  def initialize(*roles)
    @roles = roles
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @roles.include? request.env['warden'].user.try(:role)
  end
end
```

I see that the guy is using warden here, however I am using cancan, and since this piece of code makes no sense to me, I can't really make any changes to it, but from what I have tried, I keep getting the undefined local variable or method `root_path' error.

Would highly appreciate any help!

Comment: `warder` and `cancan` different things, please tell are you using `devise` gem?

Comment: no, i am using sorcery

Comment: you can`t use this example because `devise` it is warder middleware, and `sorcery` have another logic.

Comment: well can I still write my own code to user constraints in the router?

Comment: yeah tell me what you need and i can help you.

Comment: I want to change the root_path default for admin users through the router

Comment: you can't do it in routes, because you can't check user role in routes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that router should be in charge of doing that. It's hard to implement and hard to test. 
More than, it's extremely inconsistent - different users will see different things under the same url. Normally, people do wrap admin area to `/admin` scope.

So, my suggestion would be to do routing straightforward (just `/admin` scope), and put the authentication logic into controllers (e.g. `AdminController`).

If you need further advice, just ask.

Comment: so how would I implement the click on main logo logic, for example? I would like different roles to have different root_paths

Comment: Well, I don't think it's a good design then. For all the users main logo click should work the same, as same urls should lead to the same resources.

Comment: i have to disagree here. In any case, I've created all the necessary redirects from within my controller.